# Can typescript external modules have circular dependencies?

Tags: module, typescript

It looks like this is not allowed. requireJS is throwing an error on the following ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087031/circular-dependencies-in-typescript) is different as it was resolved with internal modules):

element.ts:

```
import runProperties = require('./run-properties');
export class Element {
   public static factory (element : IElement) : Element {

        switch (element.type) {
            case TYPE.RUN_PROPERTIES :
                return new runProperties.RunProperties().deserialize(<runProperties.IRunProperties>element);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

run-properties.ts:

```
import element = require('./element');

export class RunProperties extends element.Element implements IRunProperties {
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, modules can't have circular dependencies unless they are in the same file. Each file is being processed in sequence, synchronously, so the full file definition (including all of the exports for example) hasn't been completed when it goes to second file, which immediately tries to require/reference the first file, and so on.

Normally, you can break a circular dependency by introducing an interface or base class into a common definition file(s) (basically interfaces only) and having the other files use that as a common "interface" rather than directly referencing the classes. This is a typical pattern in many platforms.

Comment: Bummer, this is a major PITA. This pushes us toward having all classes for one area in a single file and I dislike having single files with numerous classes in it.

Comment: Is there a way to have tsc build a single .js file from multiple .ts files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926830/typescript-compiling-as-a-single-js-file?rq=1 -- but you still might consider creating them in a different way as I suggested. I've used the same pattern in COM and .NET for example. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. We'll try breaking it out so we don't have this problem because I agree, better to keep distinct files.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again. But if we get this wrong we're going to be suffering for years. What do you think of the idea of one giant interfaces.ts that has the interface to everything. Then a bunch of files for all the different classes (we'll put similar classes in one file). That way we have distinct smaller files for classes. And the giant everything file we're rarely in because it's just the interface definitions. ???

Comment: Personally, during the original build of an app, I really hate managing an interface and a class file and keeping them in sync. It just feels like busy work and takes time away from the actual construction of the app. It's not to say that it can't work -- it's more effort). You might consider referencing multiple files from a single file to help split them up. An "all_interfaces.d.ts" which has references to groups of interfaces.

Comment: We tried that. But we keep hitting the problem that we have circular references up the wazoo and we're using external modules because of the eventual size of the code base. I don't think we can do the all_interfaces.d.ts with external modules - correct?

Comment: Also, we do need the interfaces because we're passing these objects to/from a web worker. So we postMessage() a class and receive the interface.

Comment: Then, maybe a single file is necessary if you have that interwoven dependencies.

Comment: It would be nice if it were possible to merge certain files via <reference> tags into single external modules, while allowing the overall project to be built with external modules. The idea of having huge files with several classes embedded in them isn't pretty. I suppose this is possible with a custom build process, but it'd be nice if it was a feature built into intellisense and the compilation process.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue, I was able to fix it by creating factory class that allows registration of child classes and used Generics for instantiation.

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

See sample code below:

Base Class (abstract.control.ts)

```
export type AbstracControlOptions = {
    key?:string;
}
export abstract class AbstractControl {
    key:string;
    constructor(options:AbstracControlOptions){
        this.key = options.key;
    }    
}
```

Parent Class (container.ts)

```
import { AbstractControl, AbstracControlOptions } from './abstract.control';
import { Factory } from './factory';

export { AbstracControlOptions };
export abstract class Container extends AbstractControl {
    children: AbstractControl[] = [];
    constructor(options: AbstracControlOptions) {
        super(options);
    }
    addChild(options: { type: string }) {
        var Control:any = Factory.ControlMap[options.type];
        if (Control) {
            this.children.push(Factory.create(Control, options));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have to import the child classes any more, because I'm using factory.ts to instantiate the child classes.

**Factory Class(factory.ts)**

```
import {AbstractControl, AbstracControlOptions} from './abstract.control';

type ControlMap<T extends AbstractControl> = {
    [type:string]:T
};

export class Factory{
    static ControlMap: ControlMap<any> = {};
    static create<T extends AbstractControl>(c: { new ({}): T; }, options: AbstracControlOptions): T {
        return new c(options);
    } 
}
```

Although class constructor seems to be called at `c: { new ({}): T }` but it does not actually calls it. But gets the reference to the constructor via `new` operator. The parameter `{}` to the constructor in my case is required because the base class `AbstractControl` requires it.

(1) Child Class(layout.ts)

```
import { Factory } from './factory';
import { Container, AbstracControlOptions } from './container';

export type LayoutlOptions = AbstracControlOptions & {
    type:"layout";
}
export class Layout extends Container {
    type: string = "layout";
    constructor(options:LayoutlOptions) {
        super(options);
    }
}
Factory.ControlMap["layout"] = Layout;
```

(2) Child Class(repeater.ts)

```
import { Factory } from './factory'
import { Container, AbstracControlOptions } from './container';

export type RepeaterOptions = AbstracControlOptions & {
    type: "repeater";
}
export class Repeater extends Container {
    type: string = "repeater";
    constructor(options:RepeaterOptions) {
        super(options);
    }
}
Factory.ControlMap["repeater"] = Repeater;
```