# Import from service gives undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm just playing around with
the http stuff in the ng-book

the simple deploy is

```
/app
    /search
        search.component.ts
        search.service.ts
        search.token.ts
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { searchDataToken } from './search/search.token';
import { youTubeApiKeyToken} from './search/search.token';

console.log('AppComponent',youTubeApiKeyToken);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(searchDataToken) searchDataService) {
    console.log(searchDataService.search());
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

`search.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { youTubeApiKeyToken} from './search.token';
console.log('SearchComponent',youTubeApiKeyToken);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

`search.token.ts`

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

import { SearchDataService } from './search.service';

export const searchDataToken  = new OpaqueToken('SearchDataService');
export const youTubeApiKeyToken = new OpaqueToken('youTubeApiKeyToken');
export const youTubeApiUrlToken = new OpaqueToken('youTubeApiUrlToken');
export const YOUTUBE_API_KEY: string = 'AIzaSyDOfT_BO81aEZScosfTYMruJobmpjqNeEk';
export const YOUTUBE_API_URL: string = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

export const searchServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  {provide: searchDataToken, useClass: SearchDataService},
  {provide: youTubeApiKeyToken, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_KEY},
  {provide: youTubeApiUrlToken, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_URL}
];
```

`search.service.ts`

```
import {
  Injectable,
  Inject
} from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { youTubeApiKeyToken} from './search.token';
console.log('Search service',youTubeApiKeyToken);

@Injectable()
export class SearchDataService {
/*  constructor(private http: Http,
    @Inject(youTubeApiKeyToken) private apiKey: string,
    @Inject(youTubeApiUrlToken) private apiUrl: string) {
  }*/
  search(query: string) {
    return 'hey there'
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { SearchDataService } from './search/search.service';

import { searchServiceInjectables} from './search/search.token';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [searchServiceInjectables],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the Chrome console I can see

```
Search service undefined
app.component.ts:7AppComponent OpaqueToken {_desc: "youTubeApiKeyToken"}
search.component.ts:4SearchComponent OpaqueToken {_desc: "youTubeApiKeyToken"}
app.component.ts:16 hey there
```

Why is this:

```
import { youTubeApiKeyToken} from './search.token';
console.log('Search service',youTubeApiKeyToken);
```

undefined?

### WORKED IT OUT

It turned out typescript is guilty
the problem is with
import { SearchDataService } from './search.service';
in search.token.ts if you ditach the token in a other
file it works fine
Take a look at [Can typescript external modules have circular dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279395/can-typescript-external-modules-have-circular-dependencies)

Thanks to @Fabio Biondi to have pointed it out

Comment: Where do you provide `seachServiceInjectables`?

Comment: I've updated the post this  constructor(@Inject(searchDataToken) searchDataService) works fine

Comment: FYI it's probably a bad idea to include a valid API key

Comment: It's not mine it's ng-book stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Only for testing purpose, try to use the following code in `app.module.ts` instead of your OpaqueToken. It should work.

`providers: [
    {
      provide: 'youTubeApiUrlToken',
      useValue: 'yourUrl '
    }
]`

Answer (score 1):

I see another possible mistake in your code:

In my opinion, this code (in your app.module.ts):

```
  providers: [searchServiceInjectables],
```

Should be the following:

```
  providers: [...searchServiceInjectables],
```

Comment: I'm sure that's not necessary. Angular resolves nested arrays.

Comment: but on the other hand is a better sintax it seems clearer to me