# How do you successfully import classes that require one another using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

My goal is to make this test case work, using typescript 2.5.2 and webpack 3.8.1.  It is a simplification of a problem I am experiencing.

## The Setup

**simple html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var baz = new Baz(); // alerts 'constructor'
    alert(baz.createBar().getValue());
    alert(baz.createFoo().getValue());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the following three TS files:

**main.ts**

```
import {Foo} from "./foo";
import {Bar} from "./bar";

export class Baz {

    static bucket = {};
    private name: string;

    constructor(a: string) {
        this.name = a;
        alert('constructor');
    }

    static recordModule(indexCode: string, objectName: string) {
        Baz.bucket[indexCode] = objectName;
        console.log("Module " + objectName + " recorded with index " + indexCode);
        alert(objectName);
    }

    public createFoo(): Foo{
        return new Foo(1);
    }

    public createBar(): Bar{
        return new Bar(2);
    }
}
```

This class simply has a constructor, a static recordModule method, and two create methods.

Then, we have two similarly-crafted class files that also call a static method.

**foo.ts**

```
import {Baz} from "./main";

export class Foo {

    private value: number;

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    getValue(): number {
        return this.value;
    }

}

Baz.recordModule('F', 'Foo');
```

**bar.ts**

```
import {Baz} from "./main";

export class Bar {

    private value: number;

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    getValue(): number {
        return this.value;
    }

}

Baz.recordModule('B', 'Bar');
```

## The Problem

When I issue `tsc` at this point compilation succeeds.   I can also webpack it without failure -- but it doesn't work.  The error received is:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'main_1.Baz.recordModule')

## But it works in a single file?

The thing I don't understand is that if I paste it all into a single file -- it works.

```
export class Baz {

    static bucket = {};
    private name: string;

    constructor(a: string) {
        this.name = a;
        alert('constructor');
    }

    static recordModule(indexCode: string, objectName: string) {
        Baz.bucket[indexCode] = objectName;
        console.log("Module " + objectName + " recorded with index " + indexCode);
        alert(objectName);
    }

    public createFoo(): Foo {
        return new Foo(1);
    }

    public createBar(): Bar {
        return new Bar(2);
    }
}

export class Foo {

    private value: number;

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    getValue(): number {
        return this.value;
    }

}

Baz.recordModule('F', 'Foo');


export class Bar {

    private value: number;

    constructor(val: number) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    getValue(): number {
        return this.value;
    }

}

Baz.recordModule('B', 'Bar');
```

How can I successfully separate the classes into different files, and make it work as it does when the classes are all conjoined?

For completeness, here is my typescript config:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = [{
    entry: './main.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        libraryTarget: "this",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
        ]
    }
}];
```

Thank you very much, (I am trying to learn TS and Webpack)!

Comment: This seems like a circular dependency case - I'm not super familiar with typescript, but I'm surprised this compiles. That being said, this question may help you deconstruct the issue a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279395/can-typescript-external-modules-have-circular-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I'll just stick it all in the same file for now.  It's too bad this doesn't work; probably means that I'll have to rely on an event-based system rather than a plainly read set of classes.